How to access Tomcat Manager application only from localhost?
I wonder, if it is possible to access my Tomcat Manager application only from localhost for deployments and block access from other IPs.

As I found out, this seems to be possible via an access filter defined in the <catalina_base>/conf/web.xml
<filter>
   <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>allow</param-name>
      <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

See original article here:
https://community.progress.com/s/article/How-to-configure-Tomcat-to-accept-only-localhost-access-for-the-Manager-Application
